# Alternatives for XSLT transformations with Delphi XE8

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, delphi-xe8, txmldocument

I am trying to perform an XSLT transformation with Delphi XE8 and am running into problems. My XSL file refers to an external XSL file using an import statement whose href attribute has a relative path. The transform fails with the error "Named template 'skrivUtDate' does not appear in the stylesheet." The definition 'skrivUtDate' is located in the external XSL file. The definition looks like the following:

```
<xsl:template name="skrivUtDate">
    <xsl:param name="oppgittTid"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($oppgittTid)!=0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($oppgittTid,9,2)"/>.<xsl:value-of select="substring($oppgittTid,6,2)"/>.<xsl:value-of select="substring($oppgittTid,3,2)"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I have placed the external XSL file in the appropriate directory (relative to the original XSL file) but I get the same error (I have also tried all other conceivable directories for this external file, but none have worked). However, I can perform the transformation using EditX XML Editor, so I do not think that the XSL is invalid (Note that this XSL file was provided by a third party, and apparently it is being used successfully by some folks using development platforms other than Delphi).

Here is the opening segment of the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:ref="http://www.kith.no/xmlstds/henvisning/2012-02-15" 
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:po="http://www.kith.no/xmlstds/po/poKomponent/2009-06-30" 
  xmlns:fk1="http://www.kith.no/xmlstds/felleskomponent1" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="ref xhtml po fk1">
    <xsl:import href="../../Felleskomponenter/funksjoner.xsl"/>
```

And, yes, the funksjoner.xsl file is in a directory named Felleskomponenter.

My very simple test uses something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
var
  XML : IXMLDocument;
  XSL : IXMLDocument;
  s: WideString;
begin
  XML := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
  XML.FileName := 'C:\somepath\some.xml';
  XML.Active := True;
  XSL := TXMLDocument.Create(Self);
  XSL.FileName := 'C:\someotherpath\somefile.xsl';
  XSL.Active := True;
  XML.DocumentElement.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement, s);
```

I know that Delphi XE7 started shipping with the Omni XML DOM as well as the ADOM, but those are apparently absent from Delphi XE8. I was hoping that using a different document object model might address the problem.

The XML is pretty complicated, as is the XSL.

Does any body have any suggestions for alternative ways to perform XSLT transformations with Delphi XE8?

Comment: MSXML seems to be unable to handle the several layers of <xsl:import> elements with relative paths to the import files (there are 3 levels, with 2 imports on the third level, although those files are in the same directory as the file from which they are being imported). DIXML was able to correctly parse the XSL files, and it was easy to use, but the transformation returned an AnsiString, resulting in the mangling of some Unicode characters. I have posted a new question about DIXML here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760579/does-dixml-for-delphi-support-unicode-in-xstl-transformations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XSLT to work properly in Delphi, you need to use MSXML to load the XML and XSL files. This post gives a[n example on how to use MSXML with Delphi](http://www.techvanguards.com/stepbystep/msxml/hellomsxml.asp). The `TransformNode` uses MSXML under the hood.

Something along the following should work (taken [from here](http://www.xuebuyuan.com/888603.html), incomplete snippet):

```
var
  xmlEmployees, xslStyle : IXMLDOMDocument;
begin
  xmlEmployees := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  xslStyle     := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  xmlEmployees.load('employees.xml');
  xslStyle.load('empuksna.xsl');
  result := xmlEmployees.transformNode(xslStyle);
end;
```

Likewise, if you were to load your XML and XSL through a string, the original location gets lost. Most processors support setting the base uri, but it looks like [IXSLProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not have such option.

---

You also ask for an alternative. DIXML support libxslt which is in quite some respects superior to MSXML (though not to .NET's XSLT, which is another alternative, if you like interop'ing with .NET). [The package of DIXML](http://www.wikitaxi.org/delphi/doku.php/products/xml/index) comes with a bunch of demo's and examples in the demo folder.

If you can switch to .NET, [this (rather old) DrDobb's article shows how to do XSLT with .NET and Delphi](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin50.htm) and also shows yet another alternative for a transformation (though it assumed Delphi 7, not sure it still applies).

Comment: Thank you for your generous input. I do not yet have this working - I am still getting errors in Delphi, even though EditX XML editor can perform the transform. I'll report my progress.

Comment: @CaryJensen, if you are on a modern Windows machine, it is possible that the version of MSXML installed is not the version that you are trying to load. If the COM operations fail, try to [download MSXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988) (typically, either version 3.0 or 6.0 or both, other versions are problematic)

Comment: @CaryJensen, you can check for installed versions using [`XmlVersion.exe` or `Versions.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278674)

Comment: Still no joy. FYI: I am calling the LoadXML method on the IXMLDOMDocument instances to load the XML. The error I get is "The stylesheet does not contains a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document." There is a document element, and it appears well-formed. BTW, if I only call the Load method, I get an error saying "System cannot find the path specificied."

Comment: @cary, I assume you tested the stylesheet with an external command line processor and found it to be correct? Can you post the exact, minimal code you are trying in your question?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 on a VM. XmlVersion did not work. I can see that Delphi is loading MSXML3.dll. I installed MSXML6, but due to side-by-side installation, MSXML3 is still being used by Delphi's MSXML unit. I did run Version.exe, and if I am reading it correctly, all versions (MSXML through MSXML6) are installed.

I cannot find an external stylesheet validator that can handle this stylesheet because the stylesheet uses import statements and remote namespace references for some of its functions. FYI: DIXML also fails to parse the stylesheet. It is quite complex. Will share what I find.

Comment: @CaryJensen, if DIXML cannot parse it as XML, it is probably invalid, or [you have hit this bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973687). Namespace URIs are not dereferenced, so that should not matter. Is your stylesheet `version="2.0"`? XSLT 2.0 is not supported by Microsoft. On the [XSLT Info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) I've listed a myriad of commandline processors you can use (incl. [`msxml.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714)). If you cannot run your stylesheet from the commandline, it will certainly not work through code.

Comment: Abel: I have suspected the same thing, that something in the XSL document is funny, since it cannot seem to process all of the imports (the stylesheet imports another stylesheet, which in turn imports another stylesheet). I talked to another developer using the same stylesheets, and it appears that they had to make some minor modifications. If these modifications work, I will mark your reply as the answer, as there is a lot of good information in what you've posted. Thank you!

Comment: The problem was that the stylesheets imported other stylesheets from directories using relative paths, and those relative directories were missing. Once the various directories where placed in the correct locations, DIXXML was able to parse the stylesheets and transform the XML files. MSXML was not able to parse the stylesheets even after the directory structures where corrected. As a result, we are going to purchase a DIXML license and use it.

Comment: @cary, while it should be possible, msxml is very old, Microsoft suggests using the .net version of possible. Buying a license is probably easier.

Comment: I've been working with DIXML for a bit now, and while DIXML appears to support Unicode, the XSLT appears to return an AnsiString, and the result of the transformation contains some wrong characters. I've tried a number of workarounds with DIXML, but have not figured out how to get a Unicode string back.

Comment: @cary, let's try to prevent this thread from becoming too long, at stackoverflow the idea is one question per thread, otherwise it becomes impossible for later visitors to find the proper info. Besides, it may attract other people with more knowledge on the subject ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably redundant now, but I have found the easiest way to solve import and include path issues is by using absolute paths.

If using a relative path, it is relative to the installation directory of msxml.exe, not your exe or the root xsl. This is problematic when switching between different servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a native and cross-platform solution: [OXml](http://www.kluug.net/oxml.php) offers an XSLT engine written completely in Delphi/Pascal. It is a commercial product, though. (I am the author of OXml.)