# Does DIXML for Delphi support unicode in XSTL transformations

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, unicode

I need to perform an XSLT transformation of a complex XML file using Delphi, and have found that MSXML is not up to the task. I have found that DIXML for Delphi can perform the transformation, but the sample code that ships with DIXML for Delphi is returning an AnsiString, and certain Unicode characters in the XML file are getting mangled. I have tried modifying the demo code in a number of different ways, but none produce the desired result.

Does anyone know of a way to perform an XSLT transformation on a Unicode XML file using DIXML for Delphi that preserves the Unicode characters in the XML?

Comment: "MSXML is not up to the task" - why not?

Comment: @kobik, this question is a result of discussion in a [previous question on getting MSXML to work in Delphi with (lot's of) imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697647/alternatives-for-xslt-transformations-with-delphi-xe8), where I tried to help but, at least in part, failed. I can assume if that _can_ be fixed, DIXML is not needed.

Comment: OT: there's at least one way you can workaround this: set the `<xsl:output>` to `encoding="US-ASCII"`. This will properly escape anything using XML character entities. For a computer this does not matter (the character entity is the same as the actual character octet in an encoding supporting it), but for a human reader this can be less-then ideal.

Comment: MSXML seems to be unable to handle the several layers of <xsl:import> elements with relative paths to the import files (there are 3 levels, with 2 imports on the third level, although those files are in the same directory as the file from which they are being imported). When calling TransformNode, MSXML reports that it cannot find a namespace in an import. At least DIXML can parse the XSL files.